# I want a warning if I try to add an "index" to a "size"

Tags: c, types

I undertook a small exercise, to use dedicated types for different things in my software, instead of everything being (e.g.) uint64_t.

For example:

```
typedef uint64_t tIDX;
typedef uint64_t tSIZE;
typedef uint64_t tVALUE;
```

Of course, these types are all integers, and the compiler allows me doing anything. However, I want / expect to be able to get a bunch of warnings when I mix these types.

Maybe OK mixing: adding two indexes, or a value to an index

NOT OK mixing: adding an index to a size

Note: the compiler cannot know what I want from each custom defined type, so it should complain about all mixes of types.

So the bottom line is: while it is presumably better programming style to use dedicated types for different things (according to their use), *how can I actually make use of this*?

Note: I currently use the MinGW compiler readily integrated into CodeBlocks, but the question remains valid for any other compiler.

Comment: A `typedef` only creates an "alias" - a different name for the same thing. Since those are all the same types a compiler cannot determine that this shouldn't be allowed (or what rules you would want for it)

Comment: hmm... I was hoping that a `typedef` is a bit more advanced than that. Is there something which can help me achieve what I want? Besides hiding my data in structures and making the code unreadable. Something like a stronger typedef :)

Comment: @virolino Unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 1):

> while it is presumably better programming style to use dedicated types for different things

It is not, it's the opposite. Creating smelly `typedef` like that to hide the actual type `uint64_t` is often considered bad practice (it's banned in Linux kernel as one example).

Trust that the programmer using your code know what they are doing. A C programmer knows what `uint64_t` means but they have no idea what `tIDX` is supposed to be. Instead of trying to hold their hand, assume that they are competent. There's no "seatbelts and airbags" in C and so those used to the language tend to be more careful when for example passing arguments to a function.

In general, C has "weak typing" when it comes to diverse forms of integers, and you can usually assign wildly between different integer types without getting any warnings. In some cases it might generate warnings for conversions to/from `enum` but I wouldn't count on that either.

A dirty work-around to create an unique type would be to wrap the variable inside a struct:

```
typedef struct
{
  uint64_t data;
} tIDX;
```

This will make a variable of this type incompatible with anything else except an identical struct. But don't do this - this is also bad practice. And in case of smaller types, may involve dragging around unnecessary padding bytes as bloat.

Best practices:

- Don't create your own private non-standard type system.
- Don't create your own private non-standard macro language.
- Stick with `stdint.h` whenever possible and use it over `int`/`long` etc since the latter types are non-portable.
- Instead of limiting which types to use, look at implementing data validation, range checks etc where the true bugs might lie.
- Document how each public function should be used using comments. The explanation should contain how every single parameter as well as the return value should be used. You can peek at *nix `man` for examples of one way of doing it.

Comment: I believe portions of the Linux kernel use the structure-per-type technique.  There’s no risk of padding and passing such types as values is as efficient as passing the underlying type.  When you need the value, access the member variable.  Using the structures means you can’t pass an index to a function that expects a size or vice versa.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That doesn't really depend on the OS though, but on the ABI and what it says about structs (if anything).

Comment: Can you identify a C compiler where `sizeof(struct { sometype value; }) != sizeof(sometype)`?  In theory, there could be padding bytes, but I know of no compiler where they have been added so the two sizes are not equal.  And one advantage of comments is that such precision isn't 100% necessary.  The risk is extremely low, to the point of being vanishingly small.  Quality of implementation issues suggest that there'd never be that problem.